# How to add a home partition after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, home-directory, partitioning

I am using ubuntu 18.04 in a dual boot system with windows 10 and while installing, I did not make a home partition but left around 20 GB for it if I ever changed my mind. However due to an error I had recently with the linux modules, I realized how dangerous it is to keep important files in the root partition and how easy it is to corrupt system files.
I just opened GParted using a live USB and turned swap off.
[image]
When clicking on the unallocated space and pressing the add button, it tells me there are already 4 primary partitions.
[image]
But I just want to add a partition to the extended partition not make a primary one. Help please!

Comment: It is easy to do that see [this question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/50539/3940) - but it will still be easy to break things when root ;)

Comment: Ok I figured it out using [this tutorial.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14238/add-unallocated-space-to-extended-partitions?rq=1) but now my home partition is named "New Partition #1" instead of "/dev/sda7" Is that something to worry about?

Comment: It probably is only a [partition label](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions) but you should still see that new partition as `/dev/sda7` in the command `sudo fdisk -l` (and is must be `ext4` or any other Linux file system for HOME).

Comment: I like to label partitions. I use gparted or Disks to add labels. But to make partition as your /home, you have to copy all of /home into new partition and change fstab to mount that partition. Details: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: That is what option `-a` is for.

Comment: Ok thanks, I already labled it and it only showed "New partition 1" because it was still in queue. If I get any issues syncing the home folder, I will ask another question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by resizing the extended partition first and then pressing the unallocated space in there and clicking add.

Comment: Yes - based on your screenshots, the issue was that the 21.21G unallocated was **outside** of the extended partition